# Getting DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE/STORAGES are mutually exclusive when upgraded to 4.2

Tags: django, django-settings, django-storage

We are in process to upgrade to django 4.2. However we are facing above issue in running django peroject. We have already setup new way of STORAGES in settings.py i.e.

```
STORAGES = {
            "staticfiles": {"BACKEND": "custom.core.storage.GzipManifestStaticfilesStorage"},
            "default": {"BACKEND": "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage"},
        }
```

But its not working and getting said error in running project. But, when we manually go and remove `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` from
[django\conf\global_settings.py file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/74582b8d119a8c7d688538442b4149112b626057/django/conf/global_settings.py#L281) then at least it doesn't give above issue.
Any suggestion(s) how to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's fixed. I had a silly mistake that i was still using `django-configurations` version 2.3.1 but once I moved to `django-configurations` version 2.5. Then issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.2 `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` are deprecated and replaced with `STORAGES`.

Just replace `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` with `STORAGES` and keep the original value and you are good to go.

More info under:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-file-storage

Comment: Exactly, that's what I have already done as mentioned in question description but unfortunately that's does not work.

Comment: My apologies! Could the problem be in your custom.core.storage.GzipManifestStaticfilesStorage?

What about if you try django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage instead, the standard Django static storage.

If it works, the problem should be in your custom storage.